# Code Igniter session declaration

Tags: codeigniter, session

I am new to CodeIgniter framework. I am using 2.1.4 version. I designed a simple login form, with a javascript validation, and the home page of a site. Can you please help me to understand how to declare session , and how to destroy the session on clicking signout link.

controller file of login page ( to load  the view page login.php ):-

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
      $this->load->helper('url');
  }
 function index(){
    $this->load->view('login');
 }
 function success() {
     redirect ('home');
  }
}
```

The controller file home.php for the view home.php

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {

// local constructor will be overriding the one in the parent controller class 
// for using a constructor in any of my Controllers
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

}

public function index()
        {
                $this->load->view('home');
        }
}
```

I have designed the view page home.php, and gave the signout link:-

```
 <div class="logout"><a href="">Signout</a></div>
```

For initializing the session, i need to know, what all constructor changes/ config changes need, and the method of session destoy.

Answer (score 0):

To start session library, Go to `application/config/config.php` and change the below line:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

It would be better if you start your session in the `autoload.php`. To destroy session you would use :

```
$this->session->sess_destroy();
```

To set session :

```
$newdata = array(
               'username'  => 'johndoe',
               'email'     => 'johndoe@some-site.com',
               'logged_in' => TRUE
           );

$this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
```

Answer (score 0):

here is an controller... first of all u need to declare a session so that you have two choice to declare one is Go to application/config/config.php change the code as

```
 $autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

and follow this following method (controller)

```
 class Login extends CI_Controller{
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
   $this->load->library('session');
}
function index(){
$this->load->view('login');
}
function success() {
  $user=$this->input->post('user'); 
  $psw=$this->input->post('pswd');
   $this->load->model('validation');
  $result=$this->validation->useraccess($user,$psw);
if($result)
 {
  $this->session->set_userdata('username', $user); //setting session 
  redirect ('home');
 }
 else
{
   $this->index();
}
}
function logout()
{
   $this->session->unset_userdata('username');
   redirect('login','refresh');
}
}
```

this is model where validation done

```
Class Validation extends CI_Model{
function __construct(){
 parent::__construct();
}
function useraccess($user,$pswd)
{
 $query = $this->db->query("select * from user where username='$user' AND password='$pswd'");
 foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
 {
  if($row['username']==$user AND $row['password']==$pswd)
   {
return true;
   }
   else 
   {
     return false;
   } 
 }
}
}
```

here is a view
 login page

create 2 text box and 1 submit button and declare form action as
localhost/index.php/login/success

for logut
localhost/index.php/login/logout